# Types of pulsed Lasers in VIS area (optional with OPO)

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, fiber-optics, non-linear-optics

I have a question concerning commercially available Laser-Systems. As a chemist, I have nearly no overview over the huge market possibilities. Maybe someone can give me a short overview.

What kind of Lasers meeting the following conditions (at least partly) are available?

- Wavelength around 532 nm, possible tunable with a OPO between s.th. like 400-1000nm
- Pulsed (1 Hz - 500 Hz), Pulse energies around 5 mJ
- One can trigger it, with a external source (trigger box or spectrometer)
- Small Laser jitter (< 20 ns)
- 'Normal' pulse length (around 5 ns)
- It is possible to couple the beam in an optical fiber

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because product selection answers are not likely to be useful to future readers.

Comment: Hi, it is not about the product itself, but the type of LASER systems. There is only the restriction, that it shouldn't be a self build system. To formulate it other way: which lasers, generate short, stable pulses and are usable with an OPO? Sorry, if my question above is to specific.

Comment: What about a "normal" dye laser pumped with a YAG? A simple dye laser gives a resolution of about 0.2 cm$^{-1}$ and offers a lot of flexibility by changing the dye. You might also want a nonlinear crystal such as BBO or KDP to extend the range into the UV.

Comment: @ThePhoton He didn't ask for a product. He asked: "what kind of lasers".

Comment: @peterh, but the criteria he lists are more appropriate for searching a specific product than a general type of laser.

Comment: @ThePhoton That I agree, but I can imagine an excellent answer, what answers this question, but doesn't mention any specific product.